# How can I set a window's caption on the Java SE platform?

Tags: java, window, caption

I want my program to change its window's caption in response to various user actions.  Does the Java SE platform offer a portable way to change the main window's caption at runtime, or do I have to resort to native API JNI calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean [`setTitle`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setTitle%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: This is it - thanks!  I was searching using the Windows "caption" term and wasn't getting anywhere.  Your hint helped me improve the usability of the jpeg orientation setter jeo.  It is available online as open source at http://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20090507/

Answer (score 0):

JFrame has a setTitle() method which will set the title of the window.